# If $a,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $m>0, n >0$, Prove that [$a^m]=[a^n]$ in $\mathbb{Z_2},$

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Hello I need help with this proof

If $a,m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $m>0, n >0$, Prove that [$a^m]=[a^n]$ in $\mathbb{Z_2},$

Comment: If $a$ is even, then $a^k \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ for every $k \ne 0$, so $[a^m] = [a^n] = [0]$. If $a$ is odd, then $a^k \equiv 1 \pmod 2$ for every $k$ and it's similar.

Comment: how can I state this formally?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $[a^m] = [a]^m$, and consider the cases $a\equiv 1 \mod(2)$ and $a\equiv 0\mod(2)$ separately.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see this amounts to proving that if $a$ is even (odd), so is $a^m$ for $m>0$?